# Entity Framework / LINQ: Left join defaultifempty fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

I need to join 5 tables in a query. 3 of these tables must have relations, but two of them are optionally connected to an entry.

Because of this, I am trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` to `Table4` and `Table5` like this:

```
var cDesc = (cDesc == null ? "" : cDesc);
var cStreet = (cStreet == null ? "" : cStreet);

var q = await (from t1 in MyContext.Table1

           join t2 in MyContext.Table2
           on t1.ID equals t2.ObjectID

           join t3 in MyContext.Table3
           on t2.TeamID equals t3.TeamID

           join t4 in MyContext.Table4
           on t1.ID equals t4.ObjectID
           into join3

           from j3 in join3.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join t5 in MyContext.Table5
           on j3.StorageID equals t5.StorageID

           where t2.ObjectType.Equals(16)
           && t3.UserID.Equals(userID)
           && t1.Description.Contains(cDesc)
           && l.Address.Contains(cStreet)

           orderby t1.ID descending

           select new Table1ListModel
           {
               ID = t1.ID,
               Description = t1.Description,
               Address = t5.Address
           }

           )
           .Take(takeThis)
           .ToListAsync();
```

But this query only works for rows that has a connection to `Table4`, so I'm doing something wrong obviously.

Am I doing the join correctly? Or is the problem that I want to run a `where` on address that comes from the fifth table?

Comment: If all the joins are based on foriegn key relationships you'll find that using the navigation properties that EF provides will be less messy than using joins  https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically once you left join one table into a query any additional tables that you want to join to that one should almost always also be done with left joins.  In your case you're saying you want keep rows in Table1 that don't have a match in Table4, but then you say you only want matches between Table4 and Table5 which basically will remove all the Table1 results that didn't have a match in Table4.  Basically you want something like this

```
from j3 in join3.DefaultIfEmpty()
join temp5 in MyContext.Table5
    on j3.StorageID equals temp5.StorageID into join4
from t5 in join4.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Thank you sir for helping a noob out!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a source of your problem:

```
join t4 in MyContext.Table4
on t1.ID equals t4.ObjectID
into join3
```

This means that you are inner joining Table4 to Table1

Comment: Actually that's a group join and the following `DefaultIfEmpty` will result in a left join.  The issue is with the following inner join from Table4 to Table5 which basically undoes the previous left join.